# Steel heatbed - White stains after cleaning with IPA

Tags: heated-bed, bigtreetech, biqu-b1

So, I'm new at 3D printing and I've tried cleaning my new 3D printer's steel heated bed with Isopropyl Alcohol and it left some very nasty white marks all over the bed.

I tried cleaning it off with water and dish soap but it didn't work.

Is there anyway to clean it?
Is my bed ruined?

I'm using the stock Biqu-B1 steel heated bed.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.biqu.equipment/products/biqu-sss-super-spring-steel-sheet-heated-bed-build-plate-platform-235x245mm-printer-parts-for-filament-ender-3-3-printer?variant=31925252620386) your build plate? If so, it says it comes with a powder coating, is this coating now showing these white stains?

Comment: Yes, I think so.
So, perhaps the IPA damaged the powder?

Do you think it would still be safe to use?

Comment: do fuses/breakers trip when you use it?  if not, it's not likely to be significantly more dangerous- its still an electrically heated plate.

Comment: @Abel I think it is a steel sheet cover, not the heated bed itself.

Comment: Yes, I meant the steel sheet cover, not the bed itself. I'm very new to this so I might confuse terms, sorry.

I'm using the reverse side of the steel sheet now, so far no fires :)

Comment: A clear and well-lit photo of your bed would be useful, if you could add that to your question with [edit]

Comment: Well, finally I decided to go all in and did it all again.
Cleaned the bed again with a cotton disc with IPA but scrubbing harder than the first time, then warm water and dish soap and more scrubbing and finally dried it with a soft cloth.

White stains are almost gone now, will try later if it still has adherence for prints.

Perhaps I panicked a little too soon, lol, sorry

Thank you all